# how to use same code in my View onto different Page

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am using xamarin.forms, to create a basic KeyPad. How can I use same Code on different Pages, without copy pasting this whole code block?

I was thinking to dump this code somewhere, maybe a KeyPad view-Page. Than in my Main view-Page, I can call KeyPad, when I need it? how can I do this?

```
          <Grid RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10" Padding="0,0,0,20"
                  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource keypad_Main_BackgroundColor}">
                <Button Text="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                        Command="{Binding KeypadTapCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource KeyPad_NumBtn}" />
                <Button Text="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                        Command="{Binding KeypadTapCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="2"
                        Style="{StaticResource KeyPad_NumBtn}" />
                <Button Text="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                        Command="{Binding KeypadTapCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="3"
                        Style="{StaticResource KeyPad_NumBtn}" />

                <Button Text="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                        Command="{Binding KeypadTapCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="4"
                        Style="{StaticResource KeyPad_NumBtn}" />
                <Button Text="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                        Command="{Binding KeypadTapCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="5"
                        Style="{StaticResource KeyPad_NumBtn}" />
                <Button Text="6" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
                        Command="{Binding KeypadTapCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="6"
                        Style="{StaticResource KeyPad_NumBtn}" />

                <Button Text="7" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                        Command="{Binding KeypadTapCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="7"
                        Style="{StaticResource KeyPad_NumBtn}" />
                <Button Text="8" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                        Command="{Binding KeypadTapCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="8"
                        Style="{StaticResource KeyPad_NumBtn}" />
                <Button Text="9" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"
                        Command="{Binding KeypadTapCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="9"
                        Style="{StaticResource KeyPad_NumBtn}" />

                <Button Text="0"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" 
                        Command="{Binding KeypadTapCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource KeyPad_NumBtn}" />
                <ImageButton Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"
                             Source="icon_clear.png"
                             Command="{Binding KeypadTapCommand}"
                             CommandParameter="Remove"
                             Style="{StaticResource KeyPad_ClearBtn}" />
            </Grid>
```

Comment: create a custom control using a ContentView and then reuse it in each page.

Comment: never did this before, any links to get me started?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q="xamarin+forms+custom+control"